# iOS: CGRasterData is not included in app memory, why?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 300 UIImage objects store in NSCache in my test app. These UIImages are created by NSData read from main bundle. Size of the picture is 1024x768.

After running, app memory usage does not rised. However, the memory of "Other Process" rises heavily, from 1.3G to 2.02G, 737M.

[image]

[image]

I found that the app memory usage does not contains the 'CG raster data'. But in Allocations insturment, this part of memory is growing.

[image]

Enviroment:
iPhone XR
XCode 10.1
iOS 12.1.2

My test code:

```
- (void)mem {
    for (int j=0; j<300; j++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSString *p = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pic" ofType:@"jpg"];
            NSData *d = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:p] copy];
            UIImage *i = [UIImage imageWithData:d];
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(i.size);
            CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextDrawImage(c, CGRectMake(0, 0, i.size.width, i.size.height), i.CGImage);
            i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            [self.cache setObject:i forKey:@(ii)];
            ii++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How much memory did Other Processes use _before_ you ran your test app?

Comment: If I use 300 pictures, the memory of 'Other processes' growing from 1.3G to 2.01G, 737M, average 2.45M per picture.

Comment: Images occupy memory. What is the question?

Comment: The memory usage of the test app is only 25.3M. Memory usage of 'Other processes' grows 700+M. The question is: why the memory usage of app does not grow? This affects our judgment of memory footprint. Although insturments can detect memory increases, they are used less frequently.

Comment: Because you are using NSCache. The system knows it can drop the memory at any time so it holds it out of process.

Comment: I’m not sure what you think you gain by caching images yourself, when the runtime already has an image caching system.  Apple has very good WWDC videos on all this, you know.

Comment: Not NSCache. If I use UIImageView, app memory can only be slightly increased. I can find MMAP calls on the stack, but Apple's WWDC mentioned that CGRasterData belongs to dirty memory and MMAP belongs to clean memory, which is incredible. And app crashes when CG RasterData data is large, and since it is not counted in app memory, it is not easy to notice its growth.

Comment: I cached images myself to simulate the behavior of SDWebImage.

Comment: The images downloaded and cached by SDWebImage will not be counted in app memory. I'd like to know why, so I did this experiment. Pictures take up a lot of memory, but not app memory. I think it's very dangerous for developers to ignore this memory, because many people don't use insturments.

Comment: This article tells us, CGRasterData belongs to dirty memory: https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2018/416n2fmzz0fz88f/416/416_ios_memory_deep_dive.pdf.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the videos I was talking about.

Comment: But I wonder why it doesn't count in app memory.